# Unable to use ng-autocomplete 2

Tags: angular, autocomplete

Trying to use ng2-autocomplete following this :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-completer

I keep getting different errors, every time I try some solution I find on stackoverflow or github I end up with more errors. Please help me figure this out, I'm very new to Angular and there is a chance I'm doing something fundamentally wrong..

Current error I see :

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'datasource' since it isn't a known property of 'ng2-completer'.
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CompleterService, CompleterData } from 'ng2-completer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `<h1>Search color</h1>
            <ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [datasource]="dataService" [minSearchLength]="0"></ng2-completer>
            <h1>Search captain</h1>
            <ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="captain" [datasource]="captains" [minSearchLength]="0"></ng2-completer>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  protected searchStr: string;
  protected captain: string;
  protected dataService: CompleterData;
  protected searchData = [
    { color: 'red', value: '#f00' },
    { color: 'green', value: '#0f0' },
    { color: 'blue', value: '#00f' },
    { color: 'cyan', value: '#0ff' },
    { color: 'magenta', value: '#f0f' },
    { color: 'yellow', value: '#ff0' },
    { color: 'black', value: '#000' }
  ];
  protected captains = ['James T. Kirk', 'Benjamin Sisko', 'Jean-Luc Picard', 'Spock', 'Jonathan Archer', 'Hikaru Sulu', 'Christopher Pike', 'Rachel Garrett' ];

  constructor(private completerService: CompleterService) {
    this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'color', 'color');
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**systemjs.config.js** (ng2-completer I added here)

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      **'ng2-completer': 'node_modules/ng2-completer/ng2-completer.umd.js',**


      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue :-

**Two changes were done**

1.) The selector in the app-component has to be the tag which is being used in index.html . This is important.

2.) **In the module file :-**

import { Ng2CompleterModule } from "ng2-completer"; was added
and in the NgModule imports [] add Ng2CompleterModule as well